How to Retrieve Product Data from Admin Microservice to User Microservice in a Microservices Architecture?
I'm developing a backend using a microservices architecture with two main parts: an admin microservice and a user microservice.
In the admin microservice, I've successfully created an API to add products. Now, I want to retrieve the product data in the user microservice.
Here’s what I have so far:
Admin Microservice:
I've created a POST /api/products endpoint to add products.
I need to expose a GET /api/products endpoint to retrieve the product list.
User Microservice:
I want to call the admin service's GET /api/products endpoint to get product data for the user.
I’m using Node.js and Express for both microservices.
What is the best way to set up the GET /api/products endpoint in the admin microservice?
How can I make an HTTP request from the user microservice to the admin microservice using a library like axios?
Are there any best practices for handling CORS and ensuring secure communication between these two services?
How should I handle data formatting or transformations when retrieving product data?
